# AT+CIMI command using pyserial results in empty string

Tags: python, pyserial, at-command

Connecting to Android Phone via Putty and sending at+cimi command shows my IMSI number. (XX[..]XX are numeric values)

> at+cimi
>   
> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>
> OK

With below python code (at command g+cgpaddr):

```
def open_serial(com_port):
    my_serial = serial.Serial(com_port, baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=1, xonxoff=1, rtscts=0)
    return my_serial

s = open_serial('COM35')
s.write(b'at+cgpaddr\r')
temp = s.readlines()
print(temp)
```

The output is:

```
[b'at+cgpaddr\r\r\n', b'+CGPADDR: 1,"XXX.XXXX.XXX.XXX"\r\n', b'\r\n', b'OK\r\n']
```

If I only change at+cgpaddr to at+cimi:

```
s = open_serial('COM35')
s.write(b'at+cimi\r')
temp = s.readlines()
print(temp)
```

The output is empty string:

```
[]
```

Is there a solution for that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone meets this problem, I solved it by adding spaces between "at" and "cimi".

Before: 
`s.write(b'at+cimi\r')`

After: 
`s.write(b'at + cimi\r')`

I don't know why, but it works. Checked on another phone, PC it works with both versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a timeout before s.readlines()

```py
ser.timeout=1.0
```

In fact, I don't understand why it worked with cgpaddr on your side. Without timeout, readlines never returns on my side.

Here is the comments from pyserial doc,

> Be careful when using readline(). Do specify a timeout when opening the serial  port otherwise it could block forever if no newline character is received. Also note that readlines() only works with a timeout. readlines() depends on having a timeout and interprets that as EOF (end of file). It raises an exception if the port is not opened correctly.

Comment: I added timeout, but still the same result.
"Do specify a timeout when opening the serial port"
it's already in my_serial = serial.Serial(...timeout=1)

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: are you sure you need software flow control to be active? If you use XON-XOFF there are some specific byte values that are used to control the communication. That might be interfering with your communication if you're unlucky enough.

And a second thought: some AT commands take longer than 1 second, to be sure you are not giving up before getting an answer you'd be better off increasing the timeout to 5-10 seconds.

Comment: I don't need XON-XOFF, but with or without it, the same happens. 
So as with longer timeout, especially when another commands work with that timeout very well

Comment: you can try reading bytes instead of lines, to see if you're getting any answer at all: `ser.read(100)` will try to read up to 100 bytes from the port (if will read as many as available if there are less than 100).

Comment: It also shows empty result.
What I did, just for fun, added spaces in s.write(b'at + cimi\r') and it worked :D With read(100), readline(), readlines() now IMSI is visible

Comment: those spaces! well, great that you fixed it. This is the kind of thing you expect to be mentioned in the manual...

Comment: But with another phone and PC it works without spaces, so I have no idea what's the difference, Thanks